# Why do I get this compiler error with the djb2 hash function

Tags: hash, cs50

I copied and pasted the widely available code for the djb2 hashing function, but it generates the error shown below (I am using the CS50.ide, which may be a factor).  Since this error IS fixed by a second set of parentheses, can someone explain why those aren't in the code I find everywhere online?

```
dictionary.c:67:14: error: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
     parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses]
   while (c = *word++)
          ~~^~~~~~~~~
dictionary.c:67:14: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this
     warning
   while (c = *word++)
            ^
          (          )
dictionary.c:67:14: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
   while (c = *word++)
            ^
            ==
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for setting variables to a value. `==` is the relational operator used for comparing the equality of values. Perhaps you are finding the C++ version of the function. Perhaps it is the IDE compiler rules/config.+

Answer (score 0):

I understand about = vs ==. My question was how come i get the compiler error with code that is correct, since it is a well established hash function.

turns out is related to the cs50 makefile being more stringent than clang on it's own.  needlessly frustrating.